# How to encode calldatas inside a smart-contract without filling the inputs?

Tags: solidity

This might take a while to describe but I'll be as concise as possible.

I have written a contract who encodes the calldatas of a function as well as its arguments.

[image]

For example, if I were to say that I want to swap **1000** tokens, through path **["0xFBf02764ca98778F07b5bF6677ce09B85476a7aC", "0xa1091A624AFcab43575298447c6c60Fc54966917"]**, sent to **0x28EEd3aC3eBD21F849C4c0cA969ddb90fa01a9d3** with a deadline of **11111111111** I would get this calldatas :

```
0x8a657e6700000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003e8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008000000000000000000000000028eed3ac3ebd21f849c4c0ca969ddb90fa01a9d300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002964619c70000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000fbf02764ca98778f07b5bf6677ce09b85476a7ac000000000000000000000000a1091a624afcab43575298447c6c60fc54966917
```

Now I want to make the amountOutMin of tokens, the path and the deadline constant variables, so that I doesn't have to fill the inputs when I call the function, is that possible ?

I've tried this but it doesn't seems to work since I still have to fill the inputs when I want to call the function (through Remix or Etherscan).

[image]

Maybe I have to use a structure ? I don't know.

If anyone could help, it would be much appreciated, thank y'all !

Comment: Please include the code as text. It will make testing much easier.

Answer (score 0):

So; I've managed to do it that way

[image: contract]

Now I can simply query the function without entering any inputs and it returns me the correct calldatas

[image: calldatas]

[image]

As you can see, the calldatas are the same, which means that the function works correctly. Unfortunately it works only when I call the function on Remix, when I try to call it through Etherscan it doesn't return the same calldatas, well it does but not really. Look at the signature of the calldatas `a2a1623d`

[image]

As you can see there is `000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000e4` between the `0x` and the `a2a1623d` which isn't supposed to be here, and isn't here on Remix ! I've tried some things but I can't figure it out, if anyone have an answer thank y'all.

Comment: I'd say the issue is a bug in Etherscan.